# Rendering two images in one row react native

Tags: react-native

I have visited so many websites and read many articles but couldn't find any solution. I want a ui in which each row contains two images. I have done this by adding view tag in every new row but i want to do in in a single View tag. Kindly help

```
<View style={{ marginTop: 10 }}>
                        <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: "space-between" }}>
                            <View style={{ flexDirection: 'column', alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center', padding: 5, alignSelf: 'flex-start' }}>
                                <Image
                                    resizeMode="stretch"
                                    source={require('../assets/images/Home/zinger_ratha.jpg')}
                                    style={{ width: width / 2.2, height: width / 2, resizeMode: 'stretch', }} />
                                <Text style={{ fontSize: 18 }}>Zinger Ratha</Text>
                            </View>
                            <View style={{ flexDirection: 'column', alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center', padding: 5, alignSelf: 'flex-start' }}>
                                <Image
                                    source={require('../assets/images/Home/arabian_delight.png')}
                                    style={{ width: width / 2.2, height: width / 2, resizeMode: 'stretch' }} />
                                <Text style={{ fontSize: 18 }}>Arabian Delight</Text>
                            </View>
                        </View>
                        <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: "space-between" }}>
                            <View style={{ flexDirection: 'column', alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center', padding: 5, alignSelf: 'flex-start' }}>
                                <Image
                                    resizeMode="stretch"
                                    source={require('../assets/images/Home/mingle_bucket.jpg')}
                                    style={{ width: width / 2.2, height: width / 2, resizeMode: 'stretch', }} />
                                <Text style={{ fontSize: 18 }}>Mingle Bucket</Text>
                            </View>
                            <View style={{ flexDirection: 'column', alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center', padding: 5, alignSelf: 'flex-start' }}>
                                <Image
                                    source={require('../assets/images/Home/xtreme_box.jpeg')}
                                    style={{ width: width / 2.2, height: width / 2, resizeMode: 'stretch' }} />
                                <Text style={{ fontSize: 18 }}>Xtreme Box</Text>
                            </View>
                        </View>
                    </View>
```

[I want like this but in single View tag](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VTFvI.png)

Comment: maybe a grid view will fit : https://reactnativeexample.com/a-react-native-component-for-grid-view/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do the following:

import Dimensions from react-native,
The idea here is to give the View a width of whatever percentage of the phone screen size and then give the image a percentage of the View that would give you what you want.
For example, if I want to display three images in a row, I can give my View a width of 90% and flexWrap: wrap, and give each image inside it a width of 30% so it can only contain 3 images in a row.

You can do the following for your case.

```
import {  Dimensions } from 'react-native';
const { width, height } = Dimensions.get('screen');

// inside your render or return
<View style={{ width: width * 0.9, display: "flex", flexDirection: "row", flexWrap: "wrap", alignContent: "center", alignItems: "center", justifyContent: "center" }}>
    <Image source={require("img.png")}style={{ width: "45%", height: 200 }} />
    <Image source={require("img.png")}style={{ width: "45%", height: 200 }} />
    <Image source={require("img.png")}style={{ width: "45%", height: 200 }} />
    <Image source={require("img.png")}style={{ width: "45%", height: 200 }} />
</View>
```

or if you need to put it in a flatlist you can do something like this:

numColumns={2} // you need to specify the number of columns here

```
 <FlatList
        style={styles.dashboard}
        data={this.categories}
        renderItem={this.renderItem}
        keyExtractor={item => item.id}
        numColumns={2}
    />
```